# Trying to get my divs in a centered line. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: css, html

CSS

```
div.browseBuildsArea-pro {
float: left; 
position: relative;
width: 790px; 
height: 90px; 
background-image:url('images/builds/builds-bg-pro.jpg'); 
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

div.browseBuildsArea-pro img.champion {
float: left;
display: block;
height: 72px;
margin-left: 14px;
margin-top: 7px;
border-radius: 9px;
-moz-border-radius: 9px;
-khtml-border-radius: 9px;
-webkit-border-radius: 9px;
}

div.browseBuildsArea-pro div.build-poster {
float: left;
display: block;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-top: 10px;
}

div.progress-for-build-listing {
float: left;
width: 250px; 
margin-left: 400px;
margin-top: 0px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="browseBuildsArea-pro">
<img class="champion" src="<%THEME%>images/lol/avatars/2.png">

<div class="build-poster">
    Test Message
</div>

<div class="progress progress-for-build-listing">
    <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 100%;"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

What I am trying to achieve is basic.

I want "Test Message" content be aligned to the middle of the div automatically. (regardless of the length of string) Also, "progress bar" and additional divs on the right side should also be automatically centered to the middle.

Here is a preview of what I'm looking for.
[image: http://imgur.com/TAA7t3M]
(Both divs and content inside divs are automatically aligned to the middle.)

Tried several things but none worked. (e.g display: table-cell;) 
How can I achieve this? One little example will get me going.

Comment: Yeah. :) Had this feature working with tables, but it bugged hard on Chrome so I have to do with DIV's. That's all I could come up with my knowledge and stuck at centering part.

Answer (score 0):

To align text in the middle you need 2 parameters in your CSS.

```
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
```

Also your div is missing a height. you must add that to align it.
for your code it would be :

```
div.browseBuildsArea-pro div.build-poster {
float: left;
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
height:72px;
text-align:center; // if you also want it to align in the middle horizontally
margin-left: 10px;
margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Hi, applied this but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: @LyverKinkki Thats because build-poster doesnt have a height... editing answer

Answer (score 0):

For vertical alignment check out this article: 
http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html

And utilising what I saw from the above article: http://jsfiddle.net/tf7Cb/

This for the horizontal centering should you require it:

```
div.browseBuildsArea-pro div.build-poster {
   float: left;
   display: block;
   margin-left: 10px;
   margin-top: 10px;
   text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: I've checked your jsfiddle link, but it's nowhere near what I wanted. It looks completely messed in Firefox.

Comment: Well it was not meant to be the finished article, simply a pointer to help you along the way. Good luck with finding your solution.

Comment: Thanks. I've also tried line height, but when the string is too long, it moves the next line so way below. :(

Comment: I edited the other things out because I think they were wrong and misleading.

Comment: The first link and jsFiddle is what you should use to develop your solution out further